# Java Break while loop using AWTEventListener

Tags: java, while-loop, keylistener

I'm trying to break loop using AWTEventListener, but in 'if' after checking if I pressed ctrl+p it says error by the break;

```
try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        
        int z = 0;
        while(true) {
            robot.mouseMove(x + z, y);
            z++;
            AWTEventListener listener = new AWTEventListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                    try {
                      KeyEvent evt = (KeyEvent)event;
                      if(evt.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && evt.getModifiers() == KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
                          break; //ERROR
                      }
                     
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                };
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
            
        }
        
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you understand what you're doing when creating the listeners. You're basically creating a class right in place, and that class has a method named eventDispatched(). There's no loop inside eventDispatched(), so there's no loop to break out of.

Furthermore, it's probably a mistake to assume the event is a KeyEvent. That's a side note.

Your listener probably needs to set some field that your while loop is looking at. Instead of while(true) you need to do "while(my listener hasn't set some flag to another value)".